# cursor.execute adding delimiters to my sql query

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm struggling with this code :

```
addXml = '<bar><foo>thingy</foo></bar>' 

sql = 'INSERT INTO table(col1,col2) VALUES(%s,%s);'                 

try:
  cursor = cnx.cursor()
  cursor.execute(sql, ('some_text', addXml))
  cursor.close()
except Exception, e:
  print cursor._last_executed
  print e
```

In every SQL request I have, there this error :

```
(1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

I found that cursor.execute modify my sql request to this :

```
INSERT INTO table(col1,col2) VALUES('some_text',("'<bar><foo>thingy</foo></bar>'"));
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO table(col1,col2) VALUES('some_text','<bar><foo>thingy</foo></bar>');
```

I believe cursor.execute is adding the delimiters ("").

How could I remove this behavior ? or what should I do about this ?

```
python version : 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) [GCC 4.7.2]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine with my tests and the only thing I can think of, based on the code you provided is the reference to reserved names. Is your table name actually called table? I assume you made that up for the sake of the example but if this is real code, you may want to consider using a different name for your table. Here are the corresponding lines of code from the tests I performed:    sql = 'INSERT INTO a(col1,col2) VALUES(%s,%s)'

```
addXml = "<c><b>thingy</b></c>" 
sql = 'INSERT INTO a(col1,col2) VALUES(%s,%s)'   
try:
    cursor=db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql , ('some_text', addXml))
    cursor.close()
except Exception, e:
    print cursor._last_executed
    print e
```

Works without complaints. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did name my table for the sake of an example. In fact it's adding some simple quote ( plus the usual double quote) around each of my parameters :/ I got something like that : ("'<a>g</a>'", "'<b>a</b>'") in place of addXml :/

Comment: Bizarre. Have you tried assigning values to your query statement outside of the execute function?
  
Something like, 
  
`sql = 'INSERT INTO a(col1,col2) VALUES(%s,%s)' %("some_text", addXml)`  
  
cursor.execute(sql)

Comment: Oh god I understand now. It has nothing to do with how cursor is parsing my strings. I didn't understand the true concept of concatenation of strings in python. I was doing "bla",var,"blo" and I was expecting "blafooblo" like it works for print but nah :D. Thanks anyway for your help :)